# Call web service from jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, wcf, web-services

I'm trying to use jQuery to consume my Web service and just basically need the web service to call functions that's all.

The code I'm using in .NET is this:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://Sinvise.Service/")]
    public interface ISinvise
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void Output(string value);
    }

    class SinviseService : ISinvise
    {
        second sec = new second();

        public void Output(string value)
        {
            sec.message(value);
        }
    }
```

+

```
Uri baseAddr = new Uri("http://localhost:60185/Sinvise");
            ServiceHost localHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(SinviseService), baseAddr);

            try
            {
                Process.Start(baseAddr.AbsoluteUri);
                localHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ISinvise), new WSHttpBinding(), "CalculatorService");

                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                localHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

                localHost.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Service initialized.");
                Console.WriteLine("Press the ENTER key to terminate service.");
                Console.ReadLine();

                localHost.Close();
            }
            catch (CommunicationException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Oops! Exception: {0}", ex.Message);
                localHost.Abort();
            }
```

How would I be able to simply call the `Output` web service?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use an ajax request using [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.  Script and JSONP requests are not subject to the same origin policy restrictions.

Comment: I'll need the browser to be able to send and receive values from the service

Comment: Also I'm trying to use a normal HTML page to connect to the localhost web service, I know this isn't possible as it is cross domain calls

Comment: @SandeepBansal i is possible using JSONp (dynamically embedding a get request) but you are limited to get

Comment: Is there any way to have the HTML file hosted within the WCF Service?

Comment: @Sandeep If you want to use http methods other than GET you have enable CORS support in WCF http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/c412e600-0f4e-4a5b-8c45-bf77ed04f2a8#e9e1a5a7-9a76-41a0-ab4f-fd6ad76b18aa

Comment: @Mark thanks for the link, how would I get this to work in a WPF Desktop App that doesn't have WebInvoke?