# How can i call wcf using jquery in asp.net application

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, wcf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Call web service from jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048507/call-web-service-from-jquery)

I want to add two numbers together, the operation must be done in WCF, and the result will be 
display in default.aspx page.

How can I pass the values of my two textboxes to the WCF service using jquery?

Comment: @NickW Not a duplicate - in the other question the OP cannot use ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start by defining a new service contract:

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "add?a={a}&b={b}", 
                BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, 
                ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        int Add(int a, int b);
    }
}
```

an implementation:

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public int Add(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }
}
```

an endpoint (`~/service1.svc`):

```
<%@ ServiceHost 
    Language="C#" 
    Debug="true" 
    Service="WebApplication1.Service1" 
    CodeBehind="Service1.svc.cs" 
%>
```

and inside your web.config configure the service to enable REST:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="rest">
        <webHttp/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <services>
    <service name="WebApplication1.Service1">
      <endpoint
        address=""
        contract="WebApplication1.IService1"
        binding="webHttpBinding"
        behaviorConfiguration="rest"
        />
    </service>
  </services>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Now you could add a WebForm1.aspx to your project to consume the service:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    </form>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax({
            url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/service1.svc/add") %>',
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            data: { a: 5, b: 7 },
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```